# Neo4j unexpected exception. org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException:Failed to establish SSL socket connection

Tags: neo4j

After pushing some nodes to Neo4j, suddenly I got the exception

```
org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Failed to establish SSL socket connection.
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.TLSSocketChannel.unwrap(TLSSocketChannel.java:179)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.TLSSocketChannel.read(TLSSocketChannel.java:374)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.BufferingChunkedInput.readNextPacket(BufferingChunkedInput.java:408)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.BufferingChunkedInput.readChunkSize(BufferingChunkedInput.java:344)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.BufferingChunkedInput.read(BufferingChunkedInput.java:246)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.BufferingChunkedInput.fillScratchBuffer(BufferingChunkedInput.java:215)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.BufferingChunkedInput.readByte(BufferingChunkedInput.java:109)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.packstream.PackStream$Unpacker.unpackStructHeader(PackStream.java:441)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.read(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:397)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketClient.receiveOne(SocketClient.java:129)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketConnection.receiveOne(SocketConnection.java:135)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.receiveOne(ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.java:150)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.PooledConnection.receiveOne(PooledConnection.java:142)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalStatementResult.tryFetchNext(InternalStatementResult.java:303)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalStatementResult.next(InternalStatementResult.java:193)
```

And the neo4j server quit. I didn't find any helpful solution for this.
Note : Some nodes are getting added, but in middle of pushing nodes, I am getting this exception